# Correct way to numerically calculate a sum

Tags: c++, math

I am trying to numerically calculate a sum:

[image: The sum formula]

I fully understand that it is an easy sum, however, my mind keeps tingling me for a few days consequently, if I am doing it correctly.

Here is an outline of a C++ code that I have written to calculate it:

```
struct vecs{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float a;
};

struct vector_file{
    int id;
    vector<vecs> VAL;
};

vector<vector_file> VEC;

I[10][10]={}

double absolute_val(double xi, double yi, double zi, double xj, double yj, double zj){
    return(sqrt(pow(xi-xj,2)+pow(yi-yj,2)+pow(zi-zj,2)));
}

for (int i=0;i<VEC.size();i++){
        for (int j=0;j<i;j++){
            double integ=0;
                for (int k=0;k<VEC[i].VAL.size();k++){
                    for (int l=0;l<VEC[j].VAL.size();l++){
                        integ+=VEC[i].VAL[k].a*VEC[j].VAL[l].a/absolute_val(VEC[i].VAL[k].x,VEC[i].VAL[k].y,VEC[i].VAL[k].z,VEC[j].VAL[l].x,VEC[j].VAL[l].y, VEC[j].VAL[l].z);
                    }
                }
            I[i][j]=integ;
        }
    }
```

I only need the off-diagonal elements and do not need the upper triangular part of the matrix as it is analogous to lower triangular part. I have checked it multiple times, however, still going back and wondering, if I have done it correctly.

Thank you so much in advance for taking time to look at it.

Comment: Nitpick: your `absolute_val` actually computes a vector magnitude.

Comment: @Botje, that is absolutely correct and it is supposed calculate the vector magnitude according to the formula (just the name of a function is quite a too direct translation from my native language math terminology to English, I believe)

Comment: Your code could do with a couple of comments mapping the mathematical terms to C++ data structures, but looks correct, yes.

Comment: If you care about performance and accuracy, `double xx = xi - xj; xx *= xx;` will be better than `pow(xi-xj,2)` in both categories.

Comment: @Botje, Thank you very much! Glad to hear that it seems correct. However, what do you have in mind exactly about mapping the mathematical terms to C++ data structures (I'm probably just not very familiar with the terminology as my background is in Natural Sciences mostly)?

Comment: @Eljay, thank you very much! Yes, that is undoubtedly a very good point as it could be important when applying this for a larger scale modeling. I'm very grateful for your insight.

Comment: Always prefer `x * x` to `pow(x, 2)`. The former is guaranteed to return the best possible result, the latter might not. Note that IEEE754 mandates that `std::sqrt` should return the best possible result. You should also check for the potential for `absolute_val` to be zero. Floating point division by zero is undefined behaviour by the C++ standard, although IEEE754 does define it. Also, you will probably find it (somewhat unexpectedly) runs faster if you replace `float` with `double`.

Comment: Why do you allocate `I[10][10]` statically? Use a `std::vector` and map 2D -> 1D indices. This way your code is only correct for inputs at most size 10.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout, that is a useful remark, probably really worth implementing, if this code will get to different systems. However, as for now I am doing some calculations for a well defined physical system with a known dimension i, the easier way for me looked like just to allocate I[10][10] statically.

Comment: Oh, and by allocating it one-dimensionally as a `std::vector` it also becomes easier to store only a triangle. Good homework exercise: write a `TriangularMatrix` class with the usual access methods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. If you want to make it "more obviously" correct, I would move it closer to the mathematical definitions by defining some helper functions.

Concretely:

```
const vecs& R(int upper, int lower) { return VEC[upper].VAL[lower]; }
const float a(int upper, int lower) { return VEC[upper].VAL[lower].a; }
int num_vecs(int upper) { return VEC[upper].VAL.size(); }
```

Next, I would write `magnitude_diff` to accept two `vecs`. It is not strictly the magnitude because you're only looking at three of the four components, but I don't feel comfortable defining `operator -` for 3/4 components either.

```
double magnitude_diff(const vecs& i, const vecs& j){
    return sqrt(pow(i.x-j.x,2) + pow(i.y-j.y,2) + pow(i.z-j.z,2));
}
```

and then your inner loop stays very close to the formula:

```
double integ=0;
for (int k=0; k < num_vecs(i); k++){
  for (int l=0; l < num_vecs(j); l++){
    integ += a(i, k) * a(j, l) / magnitude_diff(R(i, k), R(j, l));                                        
  }
}
I[i][j] = integ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I really do understand what you have meant by mapping mathematical terms to C++ data structures. Thank you!